# Using MPlayer with Legacy Hauppauge FM tuner card bt878 chipset

Tags: linux, mplayer

New to this forum but have been a Linux user for over 20 years. I support an older OpenSuse 12.2 box that has one of the WinTV Hauppauge FM tuner boards. MPlayer4.1 runs fine on the console for audio and video.
I would like to run the same for the FM tuner in the card. Been looking at the Man pages for usage such as:

```
mplayer radio://[channel|frequency][/capture] [options]
```

I.e. `mplayer -radio driver=v4l radio://104.4`

each time I get:

```
MPlayer 1.0rc4-4.1.2 (C) 2000-2010 MPlayer Team

Playing radio://104.4.
[radio] Unknown driver name: v4l
Failed to open radio://104.4.


Exiting... (End of file)
```

Has anyone any luck running FM radio from `MPlayer` on the Hauppauge cards in the past? Seems like it is asking for the driver type each time.
Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackExchange!

`driver=v4l` may refer to the Video4Linux *version 1*, which is an old API that was dropped in kernel version 2.6.38. Modern kernels will probably require `driver=v4l2` instead.

The Hauppauge driver has definitely been updated to use Video4Linux version 2 API.

Comment: ah yes that makes sense. Of course even supplying driver=v4l2 in the arguments, still same issue.

Comment: MPlayer has been extended and modified over the years, and unfortunately it might be that OpenSuSE 12.2 has such an old version that the documentation found in the web is not applicable to it. What happens if you leave the `driver=` option out altogether? It should have a reasonable default value.

Comment: Tried that too with no driver specified. Get:[radio] Unknown driver name: default

Comment: Then it seems SuSE's MPlayer may have been built with radio support disabled at build time, or something like that. With luck, there might be a file in /usr/share/doc/mplayer* that describes the build options chosen.

Comment: That may be it and will check. In the meantime I have found FMTools and that is working great on this system. Fmscan picks up stations in the FM band.  fm  -d /dev/radio0 93.7